# ListBox Selection keeps looping

Tags: c#, listbox, selection

When I select an item from my list, the whole selection-process goes on twice.

```
private void serving_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Serving added to diary");
        login(null, null);
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Error);
    }
    ServingList.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

When I leave out `ServingList.SelectedIndex = -1;` the process goes on once. But I need the selected index back to -1.

What am I missing?

Handler on SelectionChanged:

```
private void ServingList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\n[#] ServingList_SelectionChanged");
        Debug.WriteLine("Selected item:" + ServingList.SelectedIndex);
        Debug.WriteLine("ID of latest TP: " + tp.id);

        String itemid = tp.id;
        Produkt temp = (Produkt)ServingList.SelectedItem;

        if (servingid.Length < 1)
        {
            servingid = temp.servingid;
        }

        WebClient addserving = new WebClient();
        addserving.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username.Text, passwort.Password);

        addserving.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        addserving.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        addserving.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://fddb.info/api/v8/diary/add_item.xml?apikey=ICPOKUI83555PU43"), "&item_id=" + itemid + "&serving_id=" + servingid);
        addserving.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(serving_UploadStringCompleted);
        Pivot.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "selection-process"?

Comment: When I select an Item from my list, that item will be added to an other list. But this happens twice with the code above.

Comment: Are there any event handlers on ServingList?

Comment: what subscribes to this event?

Comment: Yes, there is. I just pasted it in my original post.

Comment: Any event handlers for `Pivot.SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

You are causing an infinate loop.

You have your list box and changing it causes an action

Change X > Action X > Handle X > Change X (-1) > Action X

Etc.

You need to have some form of break to the loop for a condition

```
private void serving_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 

     //Break condition
     if (ServingList.SelectedIndex != -1)
     {
        try 
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine("Serving added to diary"); 
            login(null, null); 
        } 
        catch (WebException) 
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Error); 
        } 
        ServingList.SelectedIndex = -1; 
     }
}
```

By doing this, you only set it to -1 when you need to, otherwise it will continuously keep setting the selected index to -1 even though it is already in fact set.

Comment: Not necessarily infinite; if the `SelectedIndex` property is sensibly programmed, it will invoke the changed event only when the value has actually changed (which it doesn't after becoming `-1`). This would match the behaviour described by the OP, i.e. just one more call after assigning `-1` for the first time.

Comment: I just tested this method, but now, for some reasons, the selectedIndex start at -1.